# iText - How to stamp image on existing PDF and create an anchor

Tags: itext

I have an existing document, onto which I would like to stamp an image at an absolute position.
I am able to do this, but I would also like to make this image clickable: when a user clicks
on the image I would like the PDF to go to the last page of the document.

Here is my code:

```
PdfReader readerOriginalDoc = new PdfReader("src/main/resources/test.pdf");         
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(readerOriginalDoc,new FileOutputStream("NewStamper.pdf"));
PdfContentByte content = stamper.getOverContent(1);
Image image = Image.getInstance("src/main/resources/images.jpg");
image.scaleAbsolute(50, 20);
image.setAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
image.setAnnotation(new Annotation(0, 0, 0, 0, 3));
content.addImage(image);
stamper.close();
```

Any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using a technique that only works when creating documents from scratch.

Please take a look at the [AddImageLink](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/annotations/AddImageLink) example to find out how to add an image and a link to make that image clickable to an existing document:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    Image img = Image.getInstance(IMG);
    float x = 10;
    float y = 650;
    float w = img.getScaledWidth();
    float h = img.getScaledHeight();
    img.setAbsolutePosition(x, y);
    stamper.getOverContent(1).addImage(img);
    Rectangle linkLocation = new Rectangle(x, y, x + w, y + h);
    PdfDestination destination = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
    PdfAnnotation link = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(),
            linkLocation, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT,
            reader.getNumberOfPages(), destination);
    link.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0, 0, 0));
    stamper.addAnnotation(link, 1);
    stamper.close();
}
```

You already have the part about adding the image right. Note that I create parameters for the position of the image as well as its dimensions:

```
float x = 10;
float y = 650;
float w = img.getScaledWidth();
float h = img.getScaledHeight();
```

I use these values to create a `Rectangle` object:

```
Rectangle linkLocation = new Rectangle(x, y, x + w, y + h);
```

This is the location for the link annotation we are creating with the `PdfAnnotation` class. You need to add this annotation separately using the `addAnnotation()` method.

You can take a look at the result here: [link_image.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/link_image.pdf)
If you click on the **i** icon, you jump to the last page of the document.

Comment: so is there any way to reverse this code? I mean I have added annotation image with link into pdf file, now I need to remove it. removeAnnotation() just remove the annotation but the icon is still there? any idea?? :)