# iText Rectangle how to set color using setBorderColorxxx | how to add text to Rectangle

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Two questions,

1. How to hide or set color white to Rectangle box border
2. How to add text to Rectangle

---

```
    public void addLinkedtoTOC(String src, String dest,String IMG,int linkedPageNumber,int linkDisplayTOCPageNumber) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    Rectangle linkLocation = new Rectangle(320, 695, 560, 741);

    linkLocation.setBorderColorLeft(BaseColor.WHITE);
    linkLocation.setBorderColorRight(BaseColor.RED);
    linkLocation.setBorderColorTop(BaseColor.RED);
    PdfDestination destination = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
    PdfAnnotation link = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(), linkLocation, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT,linkedPageNumber, destination);
    stamper.addAnnotation(link, linkDisplayTOCPageNumber);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: API reference http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Rectangle.html

Comment: Borders defined for `Rectangle` are rendered when you add a rectangle to the actual content. Annotations (such as a link annotation) aren't actual content. The `Rectangle` class is used for annotations to define the location, *not* to define the border. Borders for an annotation are defined at the level of the annotation.

Comment: You question is very similar to [How to add overlay text with link annotations to existing pdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554413/how-to-add-overlay-text-with-link-annotations-to-existing-pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is easy. It's a duplicate of [iText - How to stamp image on existing PDF and create an anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983703/itext-how-to-stamp-image-on-existing-pdf-and-create-an-anchor)

When you create a `PdfAnnotation` object that represents a *link annotation*, a border is defined by default. You can remove this border using the `setBorder()` method at the level of the annotation as is done in the [AddImageLink](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/actions-and-annotations/adding-links-existing-documents#750-addimagelink.java) example:

```
link.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0, 0, 0));
```

Your second question has also been answered before. See for instance:

- [How to add text at an absolute position on the top of the first page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-absolute-position-top-first-page)
- [How to add text inside a rectangle?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-inside-rectangle)
- [How to truncate text within a bounding box?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-truncate-text-within-bounding-box)
- [How to fit a String inside a rectangle?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-fit-string-inside-rectangle)

I have combined both in the [AddLinkAnnotation5](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/actions-and-annotations/adding-links-existing-documents#1608-addlinkannotation5.java) example:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    // Here we define the location:
    Rectangle linkLocation = new Rectangle(320, 695, 560, 741);
    // here we add the actual content at this location:
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(stamper.getOverContent(1));
    ct.setSimpleColumn(linkLocation);
    ct.addElement(new Paragraph("This is a link. Click it and you'll be forwarded to another page in this document."));
    ct.go();
    // now we create the link that will jump to a specific destination:
    PdfDestination destination = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
    PdfAnnotation link = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(),
            linkLocation, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT,
            3, destination);
    // If you don't want a border, here's where you remove it:
    link.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0, 0, 0));
    // We add the link (that is the clickable area, not the text!)
    stamper.addAnnotation(link, 1);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

However, there's also another way to add the text and the link annotation at the same time. That's explained in my answer to the duplicate question: [How to add overlay text with link annotations to existing pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554413/how-to-add-overlay-text-with-link-annotations-to-existing-pdf)
In this answer, I refer to the [AddLinkAnnotation2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/actions-and-annotations/adding-links-existing-documents#1128-addlinkannotation2.java) example, where we add the content using `ColumnText` as described above, but we introduce a clickable `Chunk`:

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow", bold);
chunk.setAnchor("http://developers.itextpdf.com/frequently-asked-developer-questions");
```

Wrap the `chunk` object inside a `Paragraph`, add the `Paragraph` using `ColumnText` and you have your borderless link.